# PHP Code to Close Unclosed Anchor Tags

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on code that truncates an database entry and puts that onto a webpage, but because of the truncation it will often cut off in the middle of link anchor tag. Usually i can deal with this by adjusting the amount of characters being pulled, but because 5 entries are pulled at a time to be displayed i end up going back and forth at lot finding the percent balance as i can adjust the characters up which fixes one entry, but causes another problem with another entry.

I need to come up with a way to have a php function automatically close these so they don't cause problems and make the page a giant link.

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Words WHERE Date_Created = DATE('2016-10-06') AND category = 'Article' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<div class="storylist2">';
echo "<br/>";
echo '<h2><a href="http://www.AHA.com/words/display_art.php?ID='.$row['ID'].'">' .stripslashes($row['Title']). '</a></h2>';

$s = stripslashes($row['Word']);

    $s = substr($s, 0,800);  //adjust as necessary
    $s = substr($s, 0, strrpos($s, "."));   

    $s .= "...";

echo '<h6>'. $row['Display_Date'].'</h6>';
echo '<h6>'. $row['Author']. '</h6>';
echo closetags("$s");
echo "<br/>";
if($row['url'] != "")
{
        echo "<br/>";
        echo '<span class="articlelink">(<a href="http://www.AHA.com/words/display_art.php?ID='.$row['ID'].'">more</a>)';
        echo "<br/>";
} 
else {
        echo "<br/>";
        echo '(<a href="http://www.AHA.com/words/display_art.php?ID='.$row['ID'].'">more</a>)</span>';
        echo "<br/>";
}
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";

echo "</div><hr style=\"color: #006699; margin: 10px 20px; \"/>";
```

I have listed above the code that i currently have for the pulling the entries onto the webpage, I've heard that there is way to make sure the truncation doesn't cut off in the middle of a tag but in all honesty i don't know how to do this. Also in the past few days i have found some PHP that closes tags which is referenced by this `echo closetags("$s");` but unfortunately i haven't been able to get to work for the anchor tags. Please help thank you!

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I think it is only about stripping font tags? And you shouldnt use mysql_query but pdo or mysqli among other things

Comment: No, not about stripping font tags, but about having the unclosed html tags, specifically the anchor closed through a php function, i'll rephrase my question, sorry about the confusion.  I know i need to work on changing it to mysqli, i have been putting it off until i fix this.

Comment: Your `if ($count=1)` is a assignment and will evaluate to true all the time. Send text from a database through htmlspecialchars() before writing it out as html. This avoids the text breaking your html syntax.

Comment: Okay, i have removed the `if ($count=1)` and the else statement as it was needed after the IF was removed.  The htmlspecialchars() works, but it causes it to be displayed in their html format, but i need to be display in a regular text format as this is displayed on a small news site and having display in html format won't make sense

Comment: Oh, now I think I understand what you mean. `$row['Word']` is a long html text and you want to shorten it without breaking its syntax. I'm afraid you have to go via simplexml &Co: Build a tree from your html text, write it out and when you have written enough characters close the pending open tags.

Comment: Got it, I've just looked at some docs and notes for that online and i think that will solve my problem there thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `<a>` tags and leave just the anchor text for any string by running it through preg_replace before truncating it:

```
$no_a_tags = preg_replace('/<a.*?>([^>]*)</a>/i', '$1', $with_a_tags);
```